# Is there a way to get TFS check in notes for ALL changesets?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

We currently have visual studio 2015 with TFS 2010.  I am looking for a way to find a code reviewer for each one of the changesets in our team project.  I did a little research, and found two different questions that were answered, but none that help me out with what I am looking for.

I have looked into TFS Sidekicks, but it looks like I would need TFS 2015 and Visual Studio 2015, or Visual Studio 2010 and TFS 2010, which is not the configuration I have, and it isn't a configuration I can get at this time.

I am looking for a way to do this without looking at each individual changeset.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi john, have you tried my method below which may do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the code reviewer and want to find all related changeset.

You can achieve this in a command prompt by running  **`tfpt searchcs`** after install **TFS Power Tools**.

[image]

There are multiple check in note options to filter the changesets.

- For *Visual Studio 2015*, you need to install this version:
  [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)

---

If you just want to know all the check in history including *code reviewer* check in note for all changesets. Either install VS2010 and using **Team Foundation Sidekicks**  as mentioned above or using TFS API to achieve this. A similar question for your reference: [How to get history of checkins/changsets for specific Team Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491196/how-to-get-history-of-checkins-changsets-for-specific-team-project)