# TFS custom wit - Getting list of changesets ids referenced to field

Tags: tfs

Im trying to create a custom TFS wit with a custom wit that is referenced to my changesets IDs.

For example, I need a field that contains a list of changesets IDs from my existing changesets in the TFS project.

Is it possible for making and customizing such field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to work with a custom work item control.

In the work item control, you can get a list of changesets via using TFS API (use the [VersionControlServer.QueryHistory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh985570(v=vs.120).aspx) method). Also check this stackoverflow case for the details: [TFS 2010: Getting list of changeset Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493762/tfs-2010-getting-list-of-changeset-ids)

Please have a check on this link for the detailed information on how to create custom work item control: https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/